# Tabelas POO em Lua!

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, lua, lua-table

Gostaria de saber porque não está retornando uma tabela no código que eu fiz:

```
TP = {} 
function TP:new(pos, newpos, effect) 
    return setmetatable({pos = pos, newpos = newpos, effect = effect}, { __index = self }) 
end 
function TP:setNewPos(position)
    self.newpos = position 
end 
function TP:setEffect(efeito) 
    self.effect = efeito 
end

var = TP:new({x = 160, y = 54, z = 7}, {x = 180, y = 60, z = 7}, 10) 
print("is "..var.newpos) -- era para retornar uma tabela.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Os valores não são retornados porque você está tentando concatenar um objeto `table` com uma *string* usando o [operador `..`](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.4.html), para imprimir os valores da tabela, faça:

```
var = TP:new({x = 160, y = 54, z = 7}, {x = 180, y = 60, z = 7}, 10) 

print ("is")
for chave, valor in pairs(var.newpos) do
  print (chave, valor)
end
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/E1Dw6t)

Alternativamente você pode criar uma função e retornar a tabela:

```
function TP:getNewPos()
    return self.newpos 
end
```

Para utilizá-la, faça assim:

```
var = TP:new({x = 160, y = 54, z = 7}, {x = 180, y = 60, z = 7}, 10) 
newpos = var:getNewPos()

print ("is")
for chave, valor in pairs(newpos) do
    print (chave, valor)
end
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/c3CnQ1)

Comment: que estranho achei que POO em LUA seria possível retornar uma tabela sem usar pairs ou ipairs... no caso POO só serve para fazer alterações em variáveis dentro da função... enfim, obrigado! +1

Answer (score 0):

O problema ai é que tu ta tentando concatenar uma string com uma tabela, e que define o metamétodo que vai ser chamado é o primeiro operador. Felizmente pro caso de strings, tem como fazer uma implementação nesses metamétodos que vai funcionar para o que tu pretendia ai.

```
-- captura a metatable de string
local mt = getmetatable("")

-- faz override no metametodo __concat
mt.__concat = function(a, b) 
  if type(a) == "string" and type(b) == "table" then
    local at = {}
    for k, v in pairs(b) do 
      table.insert(at, k .. " = " .. v)
    end

    return a .. " {" .. table.concat(at, ", ") .. "}"  
  end

  return a .. b
end

-- com o metametodo sobreposto 
-- agora quando chamar o operador .. que é o operador de concatenação
-- a sua função costomizada será chamada no lugar da padrão
print("is:" .. {x=2, y = 2, z = 3})
```